# Read a csv in ruby with UTF-8 literal

Tags: ruby, csv, utf-8

i have this csv file

```
  file data.csv: 
  data.csv: ASCII text
```

This file has ~10000 lines with some UTF-8 literal chars.

```
For example:
 1388357672.209253000,48:a2:2d:78:84:10,\xe5\x87\xb6\xe5\xb7\xb4\xe5\xb7\xb4\xe8\x87\xad\xe7\x98\xaa\xe7\x98\xaa\xe7\x9a\x84\xe6\x80\xaa\xe5\x85\xbd\xe5\x87\xba
```

I iterate over this file in Ruby and save every line in my postgresql db

```
File.open(filename, "r").each_line do |line|    
 CSV.parse(line, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |row|
  //Save to Postgresql
 end
end
```

I have now the problem that the UTF-8 literal string is saved in the db and not the correct UTF-8 string. I can convert every line with echo -e "line" but this takes much time. Is ther a way that ruby can do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CSV.parse(line, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |row|
  row = row.map do |elem|
    elem.gsub(/\\x../) {|s| [s[2..-1].hex].pack("C")}.force_encoding("UTF-8")
  end
  //Save to Postgresql
end
```

Comment: Or something like `gsub(/\\x(\h{2})/) { $1.hex.chr }`, which might be clearer.

Comment: Thx, this works well. Can you explain in a few sentences what this code makes?

Comment: @ThreeFingerMark: It searches the string for anything that starts with `\x`, gets the next to characters, interprets them as hexadecimal (`hex`), and packs them as a bytestring, which is then used by gsub to replace the original `\xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put each cell in double quotes:

```
"\xe5\x87\xb6\xe5\xb7\xb4\xe5\xb7\xb4\xe8\x87\xad\xe7\x98\xaa\xe7\x98\xaa\xe7\x9a\x84\xe6\x80\xaa\xe5\x85\xbd\xe5\x87\xba"
=> "凶巴巴臭瘪瘪的怪兽出"
```